# Segmentation Fault (Core Dumped) using read() and write()

Tags: c

I've been out of programming in C for almost 2 years and have recently gotten an assignment in school on using write() and read().

Somewhere in the code I'm receiving the Segmentation Fault error, possibly on the filecopy function is where I'd put my money on. I was trying GDB but I haven't used that since that last time I programmed in C so I turn to here.

The code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

void filecopy(int infd, int outfd);

int fd = -1;
char *prog = argv[0];
if(argc == 1) 
    filecopy(STDIN_FILENO, STDOUT_FILENO);
else 
    while(--argc > 0) {
        if((fd = open(*++argv, O_RDONLY, "rb")) == -1) {
            // we don't have fprintf... but we have sprintf =]
            char tmp[30];
            sprintf(tmp, "%s: can't open %s\0", prog, *argv);
            write(STDOUT_FILENO, &tmp, sizeof(tmp));    
            exit(-1);
        } else {
            filecopy(fd, STDOUT_FILENO); 
            close(fd);  
        }
    }
exit(0);

}

void filecopy(int infd, int outfd) {
    // char *buf[1]; <-- causes unreadable characters outputted by write
    char *buf;
    while(read(infd, buf, 1) != -1) 
        write(outfd, buf, sizeof(buf));
}
```

The input/output
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: You're not allocating any memory for buf. Try `char buf[1]` (no stars).

Comment: Reading the file bytewise is not efficient, see answer below.

Comment: BTW instead of sprinting into a buffer and the using write you should simple use printf.

Comment: Part of the assignment was to not use fprintf but I indulged into sprintf because they wanted a formatted string with the filename and program name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`char *buf;` is an uninitialized pointer, writing data through that pointer is
undefined behaviour.

```
char buf[1024];

ssize_t len;

while((len = read(infd, buf, sizeof buf)) != -1)
    write(outfd, buf, len);
```

would be correct.

Note that `char *buf[1];` is a array (of dimension 1) of `pointers`, that's
different to an array of `char`s. Using that you would need to do
`read(infd, buf[0], somelength)`, but here again `buf[0]` would be an
uninitialized pointer and you would have the same problem. That's why declaring
an `char` array of say 1024 (you can choose another size) is the correct thing
to do.

Also in main use `strlen(tmp)` and not `sizeof(tmp)`

```
char tmp[30];
sprintf(tmp, "%s: can't open %s\0", prog, *argv);
write(STDOUT_FILENO, &tmp, strlen(tmp));
```

`strlen` returns you the length of the string which might be smaller than 29 and
if you use `sizeof(tmp)` you might be writing garbage past the end of the
string. Note also that  0 may be too small for the whole string, I'd use a
larger number or construct the string using `snprintf`:

```
snprintf(tmp, sizeof tmp, "%s: can't open %s\0", prog, *argv);
```

would be more safe.

Last thing:

```
while(--argc > 0)
    if((fd = open(*++argv, O_RDONLY, "rb")) == -1) {
        ...
```

While this is correct, I feel that this code is awkward and hard to read. It
would be so much simpler to read if you did:

```
for(int i = 1; i < argc; ++i)
    if((fd = open(argv[i], O_RDONLY, "rb")) == -1) {
        ...
```

I've never seen `open` being called with `"rb"` as the mode. My man page says:

> *man 2 open*
>
> ```
> #include <sys/types.h>
> #include <sys/stat.h>
> #include <fcntl.h>
>
> int open(const char *pathname, int flags, mode_t mode);
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> The mode argument specifies the file mode bits be applied when a new file is created.  This argument must be supplied when
>   `O_CREAT` or `O_TMPFILE` is specified in `flags`; if neither `O_CREAT` nor `O_TMPFILE` is specified, then mode is ignored.
>   The effective mode is modified by the process's `umask` in the usual way: in the absence of a default `ACL`, the mode of the created file is
>   `(mode & ~umask)`.  Note that this mode applies only to future accesses of the newly created file; the `open()` call that creates a
>   read-only file may well return a read/write file descriptor.
>
> The following symbolic constants are provided for mode:
>
> `S_IRWXU`  `00700` user (file owner) has read, write, and execute permission
>
> `S_IRUSR`  `00400` user has read permission
>
> `S_IWUSR`  `00200` user has write permission
>
> `S_IXUSR`  `00100` user has execute permission
>
> [...]

As you are neither using `O_CREAT` nor `O_TMPFILE`, this parameter will be
ignore and you are passing a `char*` as a `mode_t` which is integer in nature.
Hence your call should be:

```
    if((fd = open(argv[i], O_RDONLY, 0)) == -1) {
        ...
```

Comment: Hey awesome, I just left so I'll try that out when I'm back. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Two adjustments are needed for you `filecopy` function:

- You need to allocate space for your buffer. Right now you are using an uninitialized pointer and passing it to `read` which is **undefined behavior**.
- You need to save the return value of `read` and pass the value to `write`

The end result should look something like this.

```
void filecopy(int infd, int outfd) {
    char buf[1024];
    size_t bytes_read;
    while((bytes_read = read(infd, buf, sizeof buf)) != -1) 
        write(outfd, buf, bytes_read);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Running this through a static analysis tool gives 2 warnings:

1) The uninitialized variable that @Pablo points to

2) a buffer overrun when you sprintf *argv into tmp as *argv can very large (as @Pablo also suggested in his comment re: snprintf)